# How to properly using async function with react-redux

Tags: asynchronous, redux

I'm actually learning redux by recreating a dice game but having a hard time understanding how exactly async function come into the data flow. I've seen some examples which are not real world examples and do not provide enough information. My short question in fact is how do i subscribe to change for each of my containers children and dispatch async function from mapDispatchToProps.

here's the link to the entire code if it can help.
https://www.github.com/strugglecasino/struggle.git

Answer (score 0):

Async actions are actually just functions that you dispatch in the store.

```
const uploadStarted = () => ({ type: 'UPLOAD_STARTED' })
const uploadSuccessed = () => ({ type: 'UPLOAD_SUCCESSED' })
const uploadFailed = () => ({ type: 'UPLOAD_FAILED' })

const upload = (data) => {
  dispatch(uploadStarted())
  axios.post('upload/url', {data})
    .then(dispatch(uploadSuccess()))
    .catch(dispatch(uploadFailed())
}

mapDispatchToProps({ upload })
mapStateToProps(state => ({ uploading: state.uploading })

const MyComponent = ({ upload, uploadidng }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      { uploading ? 'Uploading...', 'Nothing is going on' }
      <button onClick=(() => upload({ test: 'test'})) />
    </div>
  )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

Here the `upload` function return a new function that take the `dispatch` function un parameter. This function will be executed when you dispatch it. You can, in your async action use the given `dispath` function to dispatch actual plain action or even an other function.

This type of async actions are called thunks.